# How to make a column of repeated text in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using this Google-sheets formula for a spreadsheet:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A1:A1000)+TRUE;"Sometext to show";""))
```

To fill 1000 columns with the same text, but I think there must be a formula or something more efficient to do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IF(1:10000, )=FALSE, "SPAM"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution really depends on why you want the same information replicated across multiple rows. Does that data ever need to change? If not you possibly don't need the column at all.

Strictly in terms of efficiency it would be better to copy-paste set values into those 1000 rows rather than using a formula, since the formula will need to be evaluated every time the sheet loads.

If you need a dynamic length of repetitions and a dynamic version of text then modify your formula slightly:

`=arrayformula(if(row(A:A) <= 1000,"this row is 1000 or less","this row is over 1000"))`

This checks all of column A and if the row number is 1000 or less it populates that field with the given text otherwise it fills the row with the alternative text

Comment: I need dynamic values and the number of repetitions is also dynamic.

Comment: in which case just revise your formula slightly:  `=arrayformula(if(row(A:A) <= 1000,"true",""))` where 1000 is your dynamic number of repetitions and "true" is your dynamic text

Comment: But your formula actually do fills more than 1000 columns.

Comment: If you want to limit the range to exactly 1000 columns then change the range:

`=arrayformula(if(row(A:A1000) <= 1000,"true",""))`

Comment: Alternatively wrap the original solution in an `array_contstrain()` formula.